# Interchanging expectation value and derivative

Tags: probability, probability-theory, derivatives, expectation

Let $\{X(t)\}$ be a stochastic process and $\{\mu_t\}$ the sequence of its law.
I know that the process is bounded by $1$ for every $t$.
I would like to prove that

$\frac{d}{dt}\mathbb{E}_{\mu_t}(X(t))=\mathbb{E}_{\mu_t}(\frac{d}{dt}X(t))$.

My idea was to write the derivative as a limit and apply the theorem of the dominated convergence to exchange limit and expectation. Is that correct in your opinion?

@edit
Thanks to all of you.

Actually the process is not continuous in time (it is cadlag). What I know is that it satisfies a stochastic differential equation as

$dX(t)= f(X(t))dt+ dM(t)$

where $M(t)$ is a martingale and it is such that $|f(X(t))|<1$ and $|M(t)|<1$ for every $t$.

Comment: Writing the derivative as a limit and trying to apply the dominated convergence seems like a good approach. However, there are some extra steps to get it to work. How did it go?

Comment: PS: Do you know anything else about the process? Given what you wrote, the answer is no, in general. $X(t)$ might not even be continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [these lecture notes by James Norris entitled "Probability and Measure"](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~james/Lectures/pm.pdf). In particular, look at Section 3.5 entitled "Differentiation Under the Integral Sign" -- it's on page 24. Theorem 3.5.1 may help; it *exactly* uses Dominated Convergence, as you suggest. The section after (Section 3.6) also talks about Fubini's theorem, which may be of help.